# Django: handler403 doesn't work, but 404 does

Tags: python, django, server, http-status-code-403

Here is content of **MyProj/urls.py**:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('general.urls')), # Main app
]

handler403 = 'general.views.handler403'
handler404 = 'general.views.handler403'
```

As you can see, both handlers point to the same view, and first one, which I need most, doesn't work! For example, data of other's user at `/obj/12` shows default browser 403 page:

> [22/Jan/2019 08:39:14] "GET /obj/12 HTTP/1.1" 403 0

But the second one works well and shows correct page (when try to access some not existing data at `/obj/768`). Why and how can I solve it?

The debug mode is off. My Django version is 2.0.6

**Update.**

Content of the **handler403.py** file:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

def handler403(request, *args, **argv):
    print('Handler 403 was called!')
    u = request.user
    params = {
        'user': u,
    }
    response = render_to_response('403.html', params)
    response.status_code = 403
    return response
```

The string `Handler 403 was called!` is never printed when I try to get this page.

Comment: Can you update your question with your custom error handler view ?

Comment: @MohammadUmair done.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My guess is that your views returns a [`django.http.HttpResponseForbidden`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponseForbidden) instead of raising a [`django.core.exceptions.PermissionDenied`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/exceptions/#django.core.exceptions.PermissionDenied) exception.

Only the `PermissionDenied` exception gets handled by handler403, a `HttpResponseForbidden` is returned as is.

Comment: Indeed! Thank you a lot `:)`

Answer (score 3):

If that's really your handler403 *file* (aka. `handler403.py`), you'll probably want

```
handler403 = 'general.views.handler403.handler403'
```

(so a dotted path to the actual callable).

Comment: Nope, it doesn't help, I already tried to specify path in different ways. Also, to be precise, `handler403` is stored in `general.view.handler403`, and `general.view.__init__` has `from .handler403 import handler403`.

Comment: You may want to hack in some debug instrumentation (that is, `print`s) into your local copy of `django.urls.resolvers.URLResolver#resolve_error_handler`, to see what it's trying to do.

Answer (score -2):

handler403 should point to a view

Try something like this:

```
from general.views.handler403 import handler403

handler403 = handler403
```